# How can I check an array of arrays to see if an internal array has both values greater than the values of the previous one?

Tags: javascript

I have come to this code, but it results in an error. The idea is to have, at the end of the program, an array of arrays with all the original arrays that meet the condition of having both values greater than the values of the previous array.

```
var data = [[68, 150], [70, 155], [55, 160]];
var result = [];

for(i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    
    var firstPosterior = data[i+1][0];
    var lastPosterior = data[i+1][1];
    var firstAnterior = data[i][0];
    var lastAnterior = data[i][1];
    
    if(
        firstPosterior > firstAnterior &&
        lastPosterior > lastAnterior
        ) {
        result.push(firstPosterior, firstPosterior);
    }
}
```

Comment: change `for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {` to `for (i=0; i < (data.length -1); i++)`

Comment: Also what does "results in an error" mean? What steps have you taken to debug the code?

Comment: Printing variables on the console with console.log individually, it worked; but the for loop was generating an error indicating variables were undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have a compilation error at

```
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++) // i is not defined. You should use let, var to declare it
```

Here it is an example

```
var data = [[68, 150], [70, 155], [55, 160]];
var result = [];

for(let i=0; i<data.length -1; i++){
    
    var firstPosterior = data[i+1][0];
    var lastPosterior = data[i+1][1];
    var firstAnterior = data[i][0];
    var lastAnterior = data[i][1];
    
    if(
        firstPosterior > firstAnterior &&
        lastPosterior > lastAnterior
        ) {
        result.push(data[i+1]);
    }
}
```

I am adding in the result only arrays that met the condition.